# Controller loading order in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have angularjs web application with following routing:

```
App.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {templateUrl: 'Home.html', controller: HomeCtrl}).
        when('/app/:app/model/:model', {templateUrl: 'detail.html', controller: ModelDetailCtrl}).
});
```

If user typed `/app/some_app/model/some_model` at the start, there is `ModelDetailCtrl` loads, it's right, but i need to load and execute `HomeCtrl` everytime before `ModelDetailCtrl` how to be with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to actual execute the HomeCtrl or can you simply just execute the HomeCtrl method explicitly from within the ModelDetailCtrl method?

Comment: There is long task in HomeCtrl, and it must be executed and only than ModelDetails must starts

Answer (score 1):

I had a different issue but my solution might be helpful in your case as well.

What if you will traffic all your routing to a single controller (let's call it 'RouteController'). As a template use a div with "ng-include" which will load a template + a controller for each "$routeParams" you have, only after your long task ended.

It will look something like:

```
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        template: '<div ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>',
        controller: 'RouteController'
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/app/:app/model/:model', {
        template: '<div ng-include src="templateUrl"></div>',
        controller: 'RouteController'
    });
```

Now, inside "RouteController" you can do your "HomeCtrl" long task and when done add your "$scope.templateUrl" logic according to what you have inside "$routeProvider". In your case an empty '$routeProvider' parameters will set to 'Home.html' and all other to 'detail.html':

```
$scope.templateUrl = 'detail.html';//Or 'Home.html' if no $routeProvider params
```

The only thing missing to close the loop is setting the controller for each template, inside the template itself, as 'ng-controller'. For example, inside 'Home.html' use:

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl"></div>
```

I hope my solution is clear and can be helpful in your case...